# Chome opens a new window on top of the existing window when I run Visual Studio

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2012

When I run my web application in Visual Studio 2012 it opens the website as I would expect in the most recently active window of Chrome that is open. This is all fine and how it has worked for as long as I have been using Chrome as my default browser for debugging in Visual Studio (all versions).

However, it has recently started also opening another completely new window of Chrome with a blank tab over the top of the existing Chrome window as well. I now close this blank window and find my running website in the Chrome window behind it.

I am not sure if this was as a result of an update to Chrome (I think so) or Visual Studio (less likely).

Has anyone else seen this behaviour? More importantly does any know how to solve it as it is becoming very annoying?

Comment: If you open Windows Task Manager, go to the Processes tab, then go View > Select Columns... and enable Image Path Name. For your chrome.exe processes, are two different paths used?

Comment: All of my Chrome processes come from C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe